# Reasoning mistake, value isn't increasing as expexted

Tags: python, algorithm

I struggle with checking if the given 'pack' of key:value items is correct, but first I would like to let you know about few facts to outline the context:

That's a AoC day 4 exercise(but I come with it to you, because I want to understand its why, and not only the solution).

My input data looks like that:

```
byr:1983  
iyr:2017  
pid:796082981  
cid:129  
eyr:2030  
ecl:oth  
hgt:182cm  
 
iyr:2019  
cid:314  
eyr:2039  
hcl:#cfa07d  
hgt:171cm  
ecl:#0180ce  
byr:2006  
pid:8204115568  

byr:1991  
eyr:2022  
hcl:#341e13  
iyr:2016  
pid:729933757  
hgt:167cm  
ecl:gry
```

and so on +250 packages(package - set of byr,iyr... separated by empty line) like that.

I've already tested every single function declared for its correctness (they're working properly), so the problem is below comment 'below' that is in the code(there are also other comments in this code in purpose of getting the problem description better)

My code looks like this:

```
def check_fields(list):
    comparison_list = ['byr', 'iyr', 'eyr',
                       'hgt', 'hcl', 'ecl',
                       'pid']
    statement = True
    for i in comparison_list:
        statement = statement and (i in list)
    return statement

def check_byr_iyr_eyr(line):
    prefix,value = line.split(':')
    cases = {'byr':{'min':1920, 'max':2002},
             'iyr':{'min':2010, 'max':2020},
             'eyr':{'min':2020, 'max':2030} }
    return cases[prefix]['min'] <= int(value) <= cases[prefix]['max']

def check_hgt(line):
    unit = line[len(line)-2] + line[len(line)-1]
    value = line[line.index(':')+1: -2]
    cases = {'cm':{'min':150, 'max':193},
             'in':{'min':59, 'max':76}}
    return cases[unit]['min'] <= int(value) <= cases[unit]['max']

def check_hcl(line):
    statement = True
    if line[line.index(':')+1] != '#' or len(line[line.index(':')+2:]) != 6:
        return False
    else:
        string = line[line.index('#')+1:]
        for i in string:
            statement = statement and (97 <= ord(i) <= 102 or 48 <= ord(i) <= 57)
        return statement

def check_ecl(line):
    comparison_list = ['amb', 'blu', 'brn',
                       'gry', 'grn', 'hzl',
                       'oth' ]
    if line[line.index(':') + 1:] in comparison_list:
        return True
    return False

def check_pid(line):
    if len(line[line.index(':')+1:]) != 9:
        return False
    try:
        int(line[line.index(':')+1:])
        return True
    except:
        return False

''' below '''

line_list = []
valid_passports = 0
function_pool = {'ecl':check_ecl,'byr':check_byr_iyr_eyr, 'iyr':check_byr_iyr_eyr,
                 'hgt':check_hgt, 'hcl':check_hcl, 'eyr':check_byr_iyr_eyr, 'pid':check_pid}
statement = True

with open('results.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line != '\n':
            line_list.append(line.strip('\n'))
        else:
            print(line_list)
            if check_fields(line_list):
                print('check_fields(line_list) == True') # this message doesn't appear in console
                for i in line_list:
                    print('prefix - i[:3]:', i[:3]) # this message doesnt appear in console
                    checking_function = function_pool[i[:3]]
                    statement = statement and checking_function(i)
                if statement:
                    valid_passports += 1
                else:
                    statement = True
            line_list.clear()



print(valid_passports)
```

For the input shown at the top, my output would be like:

```
['byr:1983', 'iyr:2017', 'pid:796082981', 'cid:129', 'eyr:2030', 'ecl:oth', 'hgt:182cm']
['iyr:2019', 'cid:314', 'eyr:2039', 'hcl:#cfa07d', 'hgt:171cm', 'ecl:#0180ce', 'byr:2006', 'pid:8204115568']
['byr:1991', 'eyr:2022', 'hcl:#341e13', 'iyr:2016', 'pid:729933757', 'hgt:167cm', 'ecl:gry']
0
```

Printing results of separating packages was added for tesing purposes(and as you can see above - it works),
and now my question and the heart of the problem is:

why valid_passports haven't increased? - and as always: that solution seems to be correct to me, and I can't find a thing, which causes problem, in my reasoning.

Please help. Thanks from advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your `check_fields` function is operating on

`lst = ['byr:1983', 'iyr:2017', 'pid:796082981', 'cid:129', 'eyr:2030', 'ecl:oth', 'hgt:182cm']`

so something like `"byr" in lst` returns False because it is only checking for the string "byr". You should first process the list. Something like:

`headers = [pair.split(":")[0] for pair in lst]`

This will give

`headers = ['byr', 'iyr', 'pid', 'cid', 'eyr', 'ecl', 'hgt']`

And this is the list you should run `check_fields` on